# How long will android take to give a latitude and longitude value of current location

Tags: android

Hi Friends im trying to take latitude and longitude value of current location.Iam moving to point A to point B.After reaching point B i start application more than 3times i got 3 diffrent lat and lang.After 3 rd time its giving the same lat and lang.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the location service that you use. For me, after setting the LocationListener usually first network location updates come in a second or two, GPS may sometimes take up to a minute.

Comment: thaks yar.If im using wifi r networkprovider its giving exact point of B at first.